# UITableView loaddata issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I connect to a server and retrieve five rows of data and then show them up on my UITableView by using reloaddata of my `UITableView.` So far so good.

Then I am trying to retrieve another five rows from the server and I use again reloaddata of my `UITableView`. I see the new data on the `UITableView` but when i scroll down to see the previous data my table loads-redraw them again (the UITableView delegate redraws the objects while I scroll down). I want the previous data but I do not want to be redrawed to improve smoothness! Is there a way to reload data of my UITableView and as I scroll down to the previous data not to be redrawed ?

I want to reload just the last five i retrieve from my server not all data.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you should alloc init your array whenever you are fetching new data from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to reload only some particular rows use

```
[MytableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:arrOfIndexpaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

You control the data that backs the UITableView datasource.  When you implement the datasource callbacks, you're retrieving data from the array or whatever data structures are that hold your data.

If you want the data to be "refreshed" after after retrieving data from the server then clear your data structure (array?) and replace the data.  Then you can call reload and the datasource delegate methods will query the newly replaced data.

Comment: I did not get it. I want the previous data already stored in my array why should i clear my data structure and then load again?